# No extension exist for esbAnalytics:decompress

Tags: wso2, siddhi, event-stream-processing, wso2-streaming-integrator

Iam trying to decompress incoming events with siddhi app on WSO2 Stream Processor.
On earlier version (e.g. DAS) there was siddhi extension esbAnalytics:decompress, but if I use this extension in SP, there is error **"No extension exist for esbAnalytics:decompress"**

```
from FlowEntry#esbAnalytics:decompress(meta_compressed, meta_tenantId, flowData, messageId)
select messageFlowId, host, hashCode, componentName, componentType, componentIndex, componentId,  startTime, endTime, duration, beforePayload, afterPayload, contextPropertyMap, transportPropertyMap, children, entryPoint, entryPointHashcode, faultCount,metaTenantId, _timestamp
group by messageFlowId
insert into TestOutputFlowEntry;
```

Is there any way how to use esbAnalytics:decompress on SP or any other way how to decompress incoming flowEntry event? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

esbAnalytic: decompress is a [custom extension](https://github.com/wso2-attic/analytics-esb/blob/master/components/org.wso2.analytics.esb/src/main/java/org/wso2/analytics/esb/siddhi/extension/CompressedEventProcessor.java) written in Siddhi 3 . In order to use it in SP, this needs to be ported to Siddhi 4 as there are API changes.

Try out the custom extension writing [guide](http://wso2.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-4.0/#writing-custom-extensions), to port this. Also, Siddhi 4, identifies the extensions using annotations, this is commented out on the generated code for ease of use. Add the following to the extended Stream Processor as in [math extension](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/siddhi-execution-math/blob/master/component/src/main/java/org/wso2/extension/siddhi/execution/math/AbsFunctionExtension.java#L43)

```
@Extension(
    name = "decompress",
    namespace = "esbAnalytics",
    description = "decompress function",
    examples = {
            @Example(
                    syntax = "FlowEntry" +
                            "#esbAnalytics:decompress(meta_compressed, meta_tenantId, flowData, messageId)\n",
                    description = "the above syntax can be used"
            )
    }
)
```

After writing the extension, place the jar in the {SP_HOME}/lib directory to use this in the Siddhi App.

Comment: Thanks for reply. What exactly do you mean by "API changes"?

Comment: It extends the Siddhi Stream Processor class, which can be used to process events. The methods available in the class have changed to include additional functionality

Comment: Actually I ported this extension to Siddhi 4 and made all necessary changes, build jar file and place it to the lib directory, but there is still same error "No extension exist for esbAnalytics:decompress". Are there any rules about name of that jar file or anything else what can be done wrong?

Comment: Siddhi 4 identifies extensions based on Annotation in the class level, I have edited the answer to include this info as well.

Comment: Thanks for reply again. After I added that annotation to the extension, build it and place it to the lib directory, same error appear again. Also I tried to use extension, which is already shipped with SP, especifically reorder:kslack, but "No extension exist" error is thrown again. It seems like a SP bug?

EDIT: If I try another extension, e.g. approximate:count - everything seems ok, and error is now gone. But reorder extension and my custom ext. doesn't work and error still appear.

Comment: Yes, I am also observing the same behavior. I have started an issue(https://github.com/wso2-extensions/siddhi-execution-reorder/issues/24) in the siddhi-execution-reorder repository to track this. Will update this after solving the issue Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Hi, this is fixed in the latest version, add the {maven-resources} in the bundle plugin <Include-Resources> to overcome this. See here (https://github.com/wso2-extensions/siddhi-execution-reorder/blob/master/component/pom.xml#L110)

Comment: Finally it's working without No extension error! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I ported this extension to Siddhi 4 and made all necessary changes, build jar file and place it to the lib directory, but there is still same error "No extension exist for esbAnalytics:decompress". Are there any rules about name of that jar file or  anything else what can be done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The above extension has been released by default in [WSO2 Stream Processor 4.3.0](https://github.com/wso2/product-sp/releases/tag/v4.3.0) onwards.